# Variable value changing after returning to the loop

Tags: c

I've been coding for a C - Binary Search Tree, but the Program always change variable when returning to the loop. I've tried debugging it and checked every pointer but found no errors.

- There is a simple run(bold for input， italic for notes)

  **a**
  Please enter name of pet:
  **aaa**     *//pet name, input*
  Please enter pet kind:
  **bbb**     *//pet kind, input*
  add pet success
  aaa         *//pet name, is correct*
  *//pet kind, return to 0*
  **q**
  0b          *//pet name, turn to 0b*
  *//pet kind, always 0*
  Bye.

The code is the next:

- main.c

  ```
  #include "tree.h"
  #define CHECK

  char menu(void);
  void addpet(Tree *pt);
  char *s_gets(char *st, int n);

  int main(void)
  {
    Tree pets;
    char choice;
    InitializeTree(&pets);
    while ((choice = menu()) != 'q')
    {
      switch (choice)
      {
      case 'a':
        addpet(&pets);
  #ifdef CHECK
        printf("%s", pets.root->head->petname);
        printf("%s", pets.root->head->petkind); // petkind back to 0
  #endif
        break;
      default:
        puts("Switching error");
      }
    }
  #ifdef CHECK
    puts(pets.root->head->petname); // trun to '\000' '372' '\333' 'b' '\376' '\177'
    puts(pets.root->head->petkind); // always 0
  #endif
    puts("Bye.");
    return 0;
  }

  char menu(void)
  {
    int ch;
    ch = getchar();
    while (getchar() != '\n')
      continue;
    return ch;
  }

  void addpet(Tree *pt)
  {
    Item temp;
    if (TreeIsFull(pt))
      puts("No room in the club!");
    else
    {
      puts("Please enter name of pet:");
      s_gets(temp.petname, SLEN);
      puts("Please enter pet kind:");
      s_gets(temp.petkind, SLEN);
      temp.next = NULL;
      if (AddItem(&temp, pt))
        puts("add pet success");
    }
  }
  char *s_gets(char *st, int n)
  {
    char *ret_val;
    char *find;
    ret_val = fgets(st, n, stdin);
    if (ret_val)
    {
      find = strchr(st, '\n');
      if (find)
        *find = '\0';
      else
        while (getchar() != '\n')
          continue;
    }
    return ret_val;
  }
  ```
- tree.c

  ```
  #include "tree.h"

  static Node *MakeNode(Item *pi);
  static bool ToLeftNode(const Node *i1, const Node *i2);
  static bool ToRightNode(const Node *i1, const Node *i2);
  static void AddNode(Node *new_node, Node *root);
  static PairNode SeekNode(const Node *pn, const Tree *ptree);
  static PairItem SeekList(Node *, const Item *);

  void InitializeTree(Tree *ptree)
  {
    ptree->root = NULL;
    ptree->size = 0;
  }
  bool TreeIsFull(const Tree *ptree)
  {
    if (ptree->size == MAXITEMS)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }
  bool AddItem(Item *pi, Tree *ptree)
  {
    Node *new_node;
    PairNode seek_node;
    PairItem seek_list;

    if (TreeIsFull(ptree))
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Tree is full\n");
      return false;
    }

    new_node = MakeNode(pi);
    if (new_node == NULL)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't create node\n");
      return false;
    }

    if ((seek_node = SeekNode(new_node, ptree)).child != NULL)
    {

      if ((seek_list = SeekList(seek_node.child, pi)).child != NULL)
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "Attempted to add duplicate item\n");
        return false;
      }
      seek_list.child = pi;
      ptree->size++;
      return true;
    }

    ptree->size++;
    if (ptree->root == NULL)
      ptree->root = new_node;
    else
      AddNode(new_node, ptree->root);
    return true;
  }
  static void AddNode(Node *new_node, Node *root)
  {
    if (ToLeftNode(new_node, root))
    {
      if (root->left == NULL)
        root->left = new_node;
      else
        AddNode(new_node, root->left);
    }
    else if (ToRightNode(new_node, root))
    {
      if (root->right == NULL)
        root->right = new_node;
      else
        AddNode(new_node, root->right);
    }
    else
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "location error in AddNode()\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  }
  static bool ToLeftNode(const Node *i1, const Node *i2)
  {
    if (strcmp(i1->petname, i2->petname) < 0)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }
  static bool ToRightNode(const Node *i1, const Node *i2)
  {
    if (strcmp(i1->petname, i2->petname) > 0)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }
  static Node *MakeNode(Item *pi)
  {
    Node *new_node;
    new_node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (new_node != NULL)
    {
      strcpy(new_node->petname, pi->petname);
      new_node->head = pi;
      new_node->left = NULL;
      new_node->right = NULL;
    }
    return new_node;
  }
  static PairNode SeekNode(const Node *pn, const Tree *ptree)
  {
    PairNode look;
    look.parent = NULL;
    look.child = ptree->root;

    if (look.child == NULL)
      return look;

    while (look.child != NULL)
    {
      if (ToLeftNode(pn, look.child))
      {
        look.parent = look.child;
        look.child = look.child->left;
      }
      else if (ToRightNode(pn, look.child))
      {
        look.parent = look.child;
        look.child = look.child->right;
      }
      else
        break;
    }
    return look;
  }
  static PairItem SeekList(Node *pn, const Item *pi)
  {
    PairItem seek;
    seek.child = pn->head;
    seek.parent = NULL;

    while (seek.child != NULL)
    {
      if (strcmp(seek.child->petname, pi->petname) == 0 &&
          strcmp(seek.child->petkind, pi->petkind) == 0)
        break;
      seek.parent = seek.child;
      seek.child = seek.child->next;
    }
    return seek;
  }
  ```
- tree.h

  ```
  #ifndef TREE_H_
  #define TREE_H_
  #define SLEN 20
  #define MAXITEMS 10
  #include <ctype.h>
  #include <stdbool.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>
  typedef struct item{  char petname[SLEN];  char petkind[SLEN];  struct item *next;} Item;
  typedef struct node{  char petname[SLEN];  Item *head;  struct node *left;  struct node *right;} Node;
  typedef struct tree{  Node *root;  int size;} Tree;
  typedef struct pairnode{  Node *parent;  Node *child;} PairNode;
  typedef struct pairitem{  Item *parent;  Item *child;} PairItem;
  void InitializeTree(Tree *ptree);
  bool AddItem(Item *pi, Tree *ptree);

  #endif
  ```

Comment: There is no question in your post. Ask a specific question. Also edit the question to provide a [mre], including an exact copy of input that reproduces the problem, the observed output and behavior of the program (including the behavior that makes you think there is a problem), and the output and behavior you desire instead.

Comment: `s_gets(...)` is defined to return a value, but in several of your calls to `s_gets(...)` you do not read the returned value.  The fact that you are debugging is good, but you are not specific with your debugging results to be of any help to someone trying to.  the phrase: _"Program always change variable when returning to the loop"_...  What variable?  Why do you think the _Program_ is changing that variable?  There are people who can help with this, but none of them are mind-readers.

Comment: @ryyker I use pointer to return a valuefrom `s_gets(...) `, and I edit the question to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0):

My question was answered elsewhere.
Modify function addpet:

```
void addpet(Tree* pt)  
{  
    Item* temp = (Item*)malloc(sizeof(Item));  

    puts("Please enter name of pet:");
    s_gets(temp->petname, SLEN);
    puts("Please enter pet kind:");
    s_gets(temp->petkind, SLEN);
    temp->next = NULL;
    if (AddItem(temp, pt))
        puts("add pet success");
}
```